# Error when evaluating SSR module even when SSR is disabled - svelte-kit

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I wanted one of my route in my app not to be server side rendered.
The way to do this will be doing `export const ssr = false` in module script or setting `ssr: false` in `svelte.config.js` as mention in [svelte docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#ssr-and-javascript-ssr)

But even after disabling ssr in both the ways, I'm still getting errors in terminal like `localStorage is not defined` which should be not there with ssr disabled.

While app still works find. But whenever i reload the page in browser this error appears on the terminal

```sh
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/routes/index.svelte:
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

svelte.config.js

```js
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),
    kit: {
        ssr: false,
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: '200.html'
        }),
        prerender: {
            enabled: false
        },
    }
};

export default config;
```

index.svelte

```html
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    export const ssr = false
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    import Yrtc from "./../helpers/Yrtc";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    onMount(() => {
        const yrtc = new Yrtc({
            roomId: 'tet-riieiiasds-di'
        })

        console.log({yrtc})
    })
</script>
test
```

Comment: This is currently a limitation, see https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1650 for more info. https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/2529 might fix this if you are going SPA-only for the whole app and don't need any SSR capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

At least nowadays (tested with SvelteKit 1.20.4), this works as advertised. Note that a few things in the question's example code were removed or are not necessary to solve the problem:

```js
const config = {
    // ...
    kit: {
        ssr: false,
        prerender: {
            enabled: false
        },
        // ...
    }
};
```

These two options individually lead to the errors "Unexpected option config.kit.ssr" and "Unexpected option config.kit.prerender.enabled" respectively, and will abort the build.

```html
<script context="module">
    export const ssr = false
</script>
```

Independently of whether it's in the `module` script, this leads to the following warning: "`export const ssr` will be ignored — move it to +page(.server).js/ts instead. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options for more information."

The reason for requiring this is that reading the `ssr` property exported from some `+page.svelte` requires actually loading the component, including imports, at which point it is too late for preventing the issue.

If the export is moved to either of these files (`+page(.server).js/ts`), it will work. Steps to reproduce:

- create a new project (use demo app template): `npm create svelte@latest no-ssr-test && cd no-ssr-test && npm i`
- in `src/routes/+page.svelte`, insert `console.log(window)`
- run using `npm run dev` to verify you get `ReferenceError: window is not defined`
- in `src/routes/+page.js` (or similar), insert `export const ssr = false`
- run using `npm run dev` to verify the site works again

Answer (score -1):

Variables like `localStorage`, `document` and `self` are not defined on the server. Use those variables inside [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount) function which is only run in the browser when the component has been rendered:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  onMount(() => {
    document.createElement(...);
    
    // ...
  });
</script>
```

<sup>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56184892/9157799</sup>

**If you're importing an external module** that depends on those variables, use the [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) function to load the module at runtime:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    onMount(async () => {
        const Plotly = await import('plotly.js-dist-min')

        // ...
    })
</script>
```

<sup>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452698/9157799</sup>